# Changing access conditions on a "magic" mifare classic 1k card

Tags: nfc, mifare

Is there a "magic" mifare classic card that enables you to change access conditions even if current access conditions are set to never change access conditions? (write ACS: never)

Comment: You are on the wrong site, this is about IT security. https://stackexchange.com/all-sites